# How many clients API gateway support for websocket connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am planning to use API gateway websocket to connect client applications. There will be millions of clients who need websocket connections to my API. I wonder whether API Gateway supports that many long live connections. What is the maximum connections it supports. If it can't support that many, what is the alternative solution would be.